# Want to call color from DB and apply it to a text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I already got the color from the database and I get the 'vColor' value. I want to apply this color to the row of data in my table

```
function onDataBound(arg) {
    gridProperPaging(this);
    GetAdvanceSearchDetail(intPageID);


    var columns = arg.sender.columns;
    var columnIndex = this.wrapper.find(".k-grid-header [data-field=" + "WorkorderNo" + "]").index();

    // iterate the data items and apply row styles where necessary
    var dataItems = arg.sender.dataSource.view();
    for (var j = 0; j < dataItems.length; j++) {
        // Get the value of the discontinued cell from the current dataItem.
        var vWorkPriority = dataItems[j].get("WorkPriority");
        var vColor = dataItems[j].get("Color");
        // find the table row that corresponds to the dataItem by using the uid property.
        //here row of data i need to color it
        var row = arg.sender.tbody.find("[data-uid='" + dataItems[j].uid + "']");

        // Add the class if the row is discontinued.
        // here condition for my work priority if the row is discontinued.
        if (vWorkPriority == 'Urgent') {
            //row.addClass("JoborderGridBackColor");
            //My try but i get no color
            row.each(function(item) {
                item.css("color", vColor);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If more clarification is needed just ask and I will try my best to answer.

[image]

Comment: Can you include an example of how the color strings that you retrieve from the database look?

Comment: Yes, a sample array of dataItems would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     row[0].style.color = vColor;
```

instead of this

```
     row.each(function(item) {
         item.css("color", vColor);
      });
```

this was the solution, I didn't try at as I were using the beautiful IDE called 'Microsoft Visual studio' which didn't gave me any prompt if what I am writing is right or wrong.